# Complex GORM query using specific columns for a struct within a struct, and other columns for that struct's attribute

Tags: go, go-gorm

Okay, this is rather complex. I currently use GORM DB, and I currently have table after joining some tables and performing several where conditions and whatnot. The table headers look something like this:

| A1 | A2 | ... | An | B1 | B2 | B3 | C1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

What I want to do is push all these information into this struct:

```
struct finalResult {
    a A
    b map[B]int64
    bTotal int64
    c
}

struct A {
    A1 string
    A2 string
    ...
    An string
}
```

As you can see, for every row, I would like to push the info of A into the A struct, create a map consisting of keys B1, B2, B3 mapped to the respective values in the row, along with their total values as part of the outer struct's attribute, and finally C as another attribute.

I'm currently stuck on this part of the code:

```
    for rows.Next() {
        var result finalResult
    
        var b = make(map[B]int64)
        var totalB int64 = 0
    
        rows.Scan(result.a) // Not sure if this will scan the A's columns into the inner struct
        // How do I get just the B columns?
        for _, columns := ??? {
            value := ??? using column and row?
            b[columns] = value
            totalB += value
        }

        finalResult.b = b
        finalResult.bTotal = totalB

        // Once again not sure how to Scan just column c into finalResult.c

    }
```

Sorry for the super long question and thanks in advance!!

Comment: whats your query? in gorm you can specify specific columns that you want to select